# Change product price when product attribute has an additional price (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

For one of my webshops im trying to achieve the following:
All of the products in the webshop have variations. 
For example Product X can be ordered in the color RED but also in the color BLACK.
Now im trying to set an additional price in WooCommerce for example the color Black.

Color RED - No additional costs
Color Black- Additional cost €30

1. How can i set this additional cost in WooCommerce? I can only set a total price for a product variation.
2. How can i display these additional costs in the option selectbox?
3. If a user chooses Color Black i want to change the product price (Add up the additional cost to the normal product price)

Below you can find what im trying to achieve:
https://product-extras.catapultthemes.com/product/macbook/

Here you can see the total price changing when you change another option.

Below is the url of my webshop:
http://demassagetafel-specialistnl.webhosting.be/winkel/mobiele-massagetafels/ct-kahuna-set-inklapbaar/

Answer (score -1):

For front-end like this:

```js
var start_product_cost=500.01;
var total_product_cost=0;


function calk_product_cost(){
   var curent_cost=start_product_cost;
   $('select').each(function(){
        var curent_select_val=parseFloat($(this).val());
        curent_cost+=curent_select_val;
   });
   total_product_cost=curent_cost;
   $('#div_for_total').html('$'+curent_cost);
}


$('select').change(function(){
 calk_product_cost();
});

$('#btn_for_buy').click(function(){
 alert('Your product price : $'+total_product_cost);
});

calk_product_cost();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="div_for_total"></div>

<select>
   <option value="0">not need</option>
   <option value="5">test option 1 (+5$)</option>
   <option value="10" selected>test option 2 (+10$)</option>
   <option value="20">test option 3 (+20$)</option>
   <option value="-20">test option 4 (-20$)</option>
</select>

</br>

<select>
   <option value="0">not need</option>
   <option value="3">new test option 1 (+3$)</option>
   <option value="6">new test option 2 (+6$)</option>
   <option value="9" selected>new test option 3 (+9$)</option>
   <option value="-3">new test option 4 (-3$)</option>
</select>
</br>
<input id="btn_for_buy" type="button" value="Add to cart">
```

Comment: As the only potential answer here, I think others should be warned not to use this. It is nothing to do with Woocommerce, and shouldn't be used with it (perhaps the OP added Woocmmerce after?)